# Android / S3 (i9300/i9305) - Disable default keyboard pop-up at lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, keyboard, 4.3-jelly-bean

**After the 4.3 update, there is a default keyboard popping up at lock screen.**

Let me describe what I mean.

- When you opened up your phone pre-4.3, it displayed the lock screen. With no keyboard or anything, just the information. Like the clock, your missed calls and such. When you tapped into the password field, the keyboard popped up. It was all buttery smooth, looked good, worked good.
- Here comes 4.3, ala Samsung. Now if you lock your phone, it will pop up the keyboard every time.

This saves one tap, that's a pro.
But:

1. It tears apart your wallpaper, as the keyboard - which won't get loaded in time - got your wallpaper, not the lock screen wallpaper.
2. As I said, the keyboard just can't load in time. This is not a bug, it's just not possible to wake it up from deep sleep and throw so much work at it.
3. So overall it looks glitchy, cheap, awful. Like some copycat Chinese fake smartphone. Which I believe the S3 is not. It's just untasteful. Ugly.

*I understand* that this was most likely a design decision, to speed up the unlock.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?
**Rooting is OK**. I mean, this thing looks so ugly, I'm fine with losing my warranty.
Just let me fix it somehow.

**Custom keyboards:** I'm using AI Type keyboard (free) as for now, but the glitch and the auto-pop up happens with any keyboard I tried. It's like there is an event defined, so it's like you would "tap" into the field.
**Custom lock screens:** I looked around as much as I could, but I only found "press to lock" apps. Basically little widgets and buttons to lock your phone. But they were no custom lock screens, just shortcuts.
**Wake-up apps:** Tried "Auto Wakeup", but it only wakes the phone up the very same way. With the keyboard, lag and all. :/

Comment: If you want to try some alternative lock screens, there are plenty: Go Locker, Widget Locker, Holo Locker... [See here](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=locker) (well, you need to sort out some "unrelated lockers", yeah, so maybe [this search](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=screen%20locker) get's closer). Might not be a "real solution", but worth a try.